# Why does my custom filter not being called with servicefilter or typefilter in .NET Core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I have a problem with the following code. I tried to implement a custom action filter with dependency injection to my constructor.

I followed the exact way according to this tutorial, but my custom filter not even being called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ifilterfactory

Here is what I have implemented so far:

CustomFilter.cs

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly UserManager<Kullanici> _userManager;

    public CustomFilter(UserManager<Kullanici> userManager) 
    { 
        _userManager = userManager;  
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User).Result;

        if (user.KullaniciTipi != Models.Enums.KullaniciTipi.Mezun)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Erişim hakkınız bulunmamaktadır.";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

My action method in my controller:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profil()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    var mezunHesabi = user.MezunHesabi;

    ProfilViewModel profilViewModel = new ProfilViewModel();
    profilViewModel.MapFromModel(mezunHesabi);

    return View(profilViewModel);
}
```

And my `program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomFilter>();
```

Any help is so appreciated.

I expect my custom filter to be called but not being called, I followed all the required steps, what's missing?

Comment: Was not able to repro. Have you rebuild/restarted the app?

Comment: Definitely tried many times, can't still get why not working.

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, my bad. I should have put my code in OnActionExecuting instead of OnActionExecuted.

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly UserManager<Kullanici> _userManager;

    public CustomFilter(UserManager<Kullanici> userManager) 
    { 
        _userManager = userManager;  
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.HttpContext.User).Result;
        if (user.KullaniciTipi != Models.Enums.KullaniciTipi.Mezun)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Erişim hakkınız bulunmamaktadır.";
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Home", null);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably consider deleting the question in this situation, since there was no problem to begin with (at least not one matching the description).

Comment: Thanks for warning about that, but i couldn't delete.